# Spring Boot Hibernate Liquibase db diff migration and update on startup

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, database-migration, liquibase

Since hibernate auto update is not appropriate for production deployment, I have replaced it by using Liquibase in order to migrate the production and development db.
I've based my config on those two great tutorials :
http://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app
http://www.operatornew.com/2017/07/automatic-db-migrations-for-spring-boot-with-liquibase.html

Everything is working fine in development however as far as I know I can't run mvn liquibase:diff and liquibase:update in production since the production server has no access to the application project. 
In addition it could be nice to save time by avoiding running those maven command on each pull request. That's why I would like to know how could I run liquibase:diff on spring boot application startup to generate differences between current jpa model and db then update the db scheme without removing data with the db diff file using maven or java ?